# PHP date inputted in d.m.Y to mysql innoDB, possible to fix?

Tags: php, mysql

I started working on old code and noticed that in PHP code `$date` is inputted in `d-m-Y` format to MySQL isntead of `Y-m-d` so in DB date `24.06.2015` lookslike `stu2024-06-20` in DB. All new Data is put in correct format but there is 7000 lines with wrong format already in DB.

My question is it possible to fix the wrong dates already put in the DB or read and parsed to some other format to show correct data on client?

Comment: I don't see how you can fix that data as there is no way to map `2024-06-20` to `2015-06-24`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here according to your question, is that you can't guess the year. The day you may parse it from the last two digits of the year. If you have the certain that all those records has 2015 as the year, then is a bonus.
Maybe you can sort by id (if is autoincrement) and try to guess if correspond to this year or previous one, or at least, have a notion for most records of the time frame you're dealing with.

Whatever solution you found, do not parse this and show it to the client, fix the records in the database, put exceptions for this sort of things always end up bad.

Answer (score -1):

normally you can parse the date from a date_string to a timestamp in which you have then the datetime in an useable form.

have a look at this function: [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score -1):

You can parse the dates and replace them with correct parameters.
Here date 24 is replaced with 2024 so you can skip first two digits and you will get the date. Month is correct no need to make changes in it and finally replace all with year 2015.

Write the php script for this which will take all dates as input and convert them to correct one